# linux driver for interrupt controller : char or platform

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am beginner in  linux drivers,im  trying to develop a driver for an interrupt controller.
this block is implemented on  FPGA , running under linux with  RiscV architecture.
I would need help with the following questions:

1. Can I make this linux driver as a "char driver" or else, it must be a "platform driver" or even  (IRQChip driver!: Arm) ;
2. I saw the driver of Xilinx AXI controler , what is the type of the driver? https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/irqchip/irq-xilinx-intc.c
3. where  the interrupt handling functions should  be implemented if it is a char driver: in the functions (file_operations e.g. Open)
   or it's IOCTL, same question for a driver platform;
4. Do you have a skeleton to follow for developing the driver of this interrupt controller or steps .

Comment: I believe it’s already in kernel, if IP block is built-in in FPGA. Otherwise you need to implement an IRQ controller driver, like it’s done for the standard ones,

Comment: 2. Xilinx Interrupt controller driver for the IP that is built-in in that FPGA and connected to the AXI bus (this bus is a backbone inside SoC for low speed peripheral, not sure if it can be used for communication with RAM or GPU).

Comment: Interrupt controller driver is **provider** of the resource. It’s not its business to know about handlers.

Comment: 4. Plenty examples in the kernel source tree.

Comment: I don't see a driver register call in the Xilinx code.  See platform.rst in the source for hints on making a proper platform driver.

Comment: Although there is some support for platform drivers for interrupt controllers (using the `IRQCHIP_PLATFORM_DRIVER_BEGIN`, `IRQCHIP_MATCH` and `IRQCHIP_PLATFORM_DRIVER_END` macros in `<linux/irqchip.h>`), nothing actually seems to use it. Also, the concept of a "char" driver for an interrupt controller seems quite bizarre to me. So I think you should make a normal irqchip driver registered by the `IRQCHIP_DECLARE` macro. Note that there are already interrupt controller drivers for SiFive Platform-Level Interrupt Controller, and for RISC-V Local Interrupt Controller.